# Why should I use the action decorator in mobx

Tags: mobx

I'm trying to get my head around the usefulness of the action decorator in mobx, even after reading the doc, https://mobx.js.org/refguide/action.html

Still wondering why I should use @action or @action.bound, other than to enforce a pattern where a component cannot change the observable directly.

The above article mentions providing "useful debugging information". But where can I find this info? F12->Console doesn't show anything when calling an @action or @action.bound method.

Or am I doing something wrong in the below code?

Should I install some mobx debugger? Thanks.

```
class CommentStore {
    @observable commentData = [];

    @action.bound
    updateComment(id, name) {     
        this.commentData.map(p => p.id === id ? p.name = name : p.name = p.name);      
    }
      ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mutate more than an observable variables inside a method which is not decorated by @action, your derivations (autorun) will run multiple time. This issue is not present when you work with react. render function will run only once.

one of the things which @action decorator do is to prevent multiple invocation of your derivations.

Comment: Hi Ehssan, what is a derivation? A computed value? I don't use autorun..

Comment: And in the above example did I make use of it properly? Is it @ action or @ action.bound, don't see the difference

Comment: Derivations stands for *computed values* and *reactions*. As I said if you use the observable values only in react render method there is no need to use @action.