# Mobx observable state properties with typescript

Tags: typescript, mobx

The question is about how to do things right.

As i understand the official Mobx documentation (but i think i missed something), observed store properties should be updated only through actions.
If so, should i realy create actions for all observed propereties? (then what is `observable` for if it doesn't track changes without action?)
And in order to prevent direct property update i need to hide the property itself and create public getter and setter for it (sounds like a lot of additional code).
So, since i'm starting a new project, i want to know if i understand Mobx correctly, because it won't be easy to rewrite all this later.

Thanks for your help!

P.S. something from the documentation:

> All applications have actions. An action is any piece of code that modifies the state.

> MobX requires that you declare your actions, although makeAutoObservable can automate much of this job.

`makeAutoObservable` rules:

- All own properties become `observable`.
- All getters become `computed`.
- All setters become `action`.
- All functions on prototype become `autoAction`.

Comment: This question is very opinionated, nobody can tell you how to do things right. Technically no, `observable` can easily be updated without `action`s. So do what you think is right for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out a little better:

- `observable` properties can easily be updated without `action`, as @Danila said
- `action` can improve performance in some cases, here some links:
  [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53342344/why-should-i-use-the-action-decorator-in-mobx) and [issue on github](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/issues/505)